# No funciona mostrar el resultado del buscador en la tabla

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Trato de hacer un buscador para esta tabla (con base de datos MySQL) que me muestre la fila que busco mediante la columna `dni`, pero aún no logro que me aparezca solamente la fila que busco. Aún no veo cambios en la tabla:

[image: Captura de pantalla de la tabla]
[image: Captura de pantalla del buscador]

Éste es mi código PHP para el buscador, donde debe tomar una similitud con el `dni` y mostrarme la fila que tenga el `dni` que busco:

```
<?php include("conexion.php");

$buscador= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trabajador WHERE dni LIKE LOWER('%".$_POST["buscar"]."%') ");
$numero = mysql_num_rows($buscador);
?>

<?php while($resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscador)){ ?>
    <?php
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $muestra['Id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $muestra['nombre'] . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $muestra['apellido'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $muestra['dni'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $muestra['seminario'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    ?>
}

?>
```

Éste es el `index.php`. Intenté agregar un JavaScript y XHR para que la función del botón me muestre la fila que quiero, pero sigue igual.

```
<body>

    <div id="datos_buscador">
        <table>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>APELLIDO</th>
            <th>CORREO</th>
            <th>DNI</th>

            <?php

                foreach($arrDatos as $muestra){
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $muestra['Id'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $muestra['nombre'] . '</td>'; 
                    echo '<td>' . $muestra['apellido'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $muestra['correo'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $muestra['dni'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            ?>

        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
        <input type="number" class="buscadores" name="buscadorT" id="buscadorT" placeholder="Busqueda por DNI (Solo numeros)"> 
        </svg>
        <button onclick="buscar_datos($('#buscadorT').val();" name="Buscar" id="btBuscar">Buscar</button>

    <!-- <a href="RegTrabajadores.php"><input type="button" id="NuevoRegistro" value="Nuevo Registro"></input></a>
    <a href="ListaParticipantes.php"><input type="button" id="btListas" value="Lista de partipantes"></input></a> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buscar_datos(consulta){
             var parametros = {"consulta": consulta}
                $.ajax({
                    data: parametros,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../php/load.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        document.getElementById("datos_buscador".innerHTML = data);
                    }
                    });
                }
    </script> 
</body>
```

Ésta es la `conexion.php` de la base de datos `ddw401` y la tabla que uso es `trabajador`. La conexión siempre es exitosa.

```
<?php
    
    try{

        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ddw401','root','');
        echo "conexion exitosa";
    }
    catch(Exception $e){

        die($e->getMessage());

    }
?>
```

Comment: Has probado que esa query valga en tu gestor de base de datos?

Comment: Deberias cambiar tu versión de PHP pues si estás usando funciones `mysql_` es que es muy antigua y facilmente inyectable.  Aprende a usar funciones `PDO` o `mysqli_` en su lugar y sentencias **prepare**

Comment: Estás mezclando el establecimiento de conexión con MySQL a través de PDO con el uso de las llamadas a funciones obsoletas `mysql_*`. Por favor, sé coherente con tu código :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás mezclando el establecimiento de la conexión al servidor MySQL usando `PDO` con el uso de las llamadas a las funciones obsoletas `mysql_*`.

Para arreglarlo deberías cambiar la función `mysql_query` por `PDO::query()` o `PDO::prepare()` y `mysql_fetch_assoc` por `PDOStatement::fetch()`:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";

$buscador = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM trabajador
    WHERE
        dni LIKE LOWER(" . $db->quote($_POST["consulta"]) . ")
");
$numero = $buscador->rowCount();
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NOMBRE</th>
    <th>APELLIDO</th>
    <th>CORREO</th>
    <th>DNI</th>
  </tr>
  <?php while ($resultado = $buscador->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($resultado['Id']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($resultado['nombre']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($resultado['apellido']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($resultado['dni']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($resultado['seminario']) ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Cambios en el código PHP:

- Tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Para solucionarlo debes usar consultas preparadas o bien las funciones de escapado de cadenas (en este ejemplo he usado `PDO::quote()`).
- Tu código puede sufrir [problemas de XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Para evitarlo debes usar `htmlspecialchars()` cuando envíes texto al navegador.
- El bucle estaba iterando una variable y en su interior accediendo a una inexistente (`$muestra` en vez de `$resultado`).
- En el código JavaScript envías los datos mediante el campo POST `consulta`, sin embargo accedías al campo `buscar`.

---

Por último, tienes varias erratas en el código JavaScript.

El primero está en el HTML (fíjate en el paréntesis que te faltaba):

```
<button
    onclick="buscar_datos($('#buscadorT').val())"
    name="Buscar"
    id="btBuscar"
>Buscar</button>
```

También podrías haberlo hecho así:

```
<button
    onclick="buscar_datos(buscadorT.value)"
    name="Buscar"
    id="btBuscar"
>Buscar</button>
```

O también:

```
<script>
btBuscar.addEventListener("click", evento => {
    buscar_datos(buscadorT.value);
});
</script>
```

El segundo está en el cambio del contenido de `#datos_buscador`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function buscar_datos(consulta) {
    $.ajax({
        /* Sencillez para conseguir { consulta: consulta } */
        data: { consulta },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../php/load.php',
        success: function(data) {
            /* Errata aquí: mira los paréntesis */
            document.getElementById("datos_buscador").innerHTML = data;
            /* Mejor método */
            datos_buscador.innerHTML = data;
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias esto me ayudo bastante

Comment: Queda otra errata más. Acabo de ver que en Javascript mandas la variable con un nombre pero luego accedes al campo `$_POST` con otro diferente.